# Postgres: How to update independent columns in parallel?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing

I initialize a table with ~120M rows and few columns (`a,b,c,d`). After the initialization, I want to acompy these columns with some precomputed metrics such as `a+b, (c+d)/a` etc.

**Independence assumption:** In reality, the metrics are pretty expensive selections and joins which are irrelevant for the sake of the question. However, the metrics are completely independent (i.e. they can be computed in parallel without any dependency on each other). That's why I would like to find out a way of persuading postgres to perform `UPDATE`s in parallel.

**Read-only constrain:** After this procedure, the database will not be modified in any way i.e. from now on, only `SELECT` queries will be performed. I mention this because, maybe, it is possible to relax the postgres locking system a bit.

**The addition of the extra columns** is currently executed in two steps as follows:

1. Create the columns (sequentially):

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD "x" ...;
ALTER TABLE tab ADD "y" ...;
...
```

2. Update the columns with individual metrics. I'm executing these updates in parallel (either via coroutines or subprocesses):

```
[query 1] UPDATE tab SET "x" = ...
[query 2] UPDATE tab SET "y" = ...
...
```

**Locks:** Even though I'm able to run the very same queries in their read-only `SELECT` versions in parallel, I'm unable to perform the `UPDATE`s. From what I've read, it seems like postgres is locking individual rows for updated which is unfortunate for my case. I'm either getting deadlocks or the queries are executed on a single core and there is no speedup (baseline is executing the queries sequentially).

**Question:** how to effectively perform many column-wise independent updates in parallel? I'm looking for high-level answer rather then actual query. What approach should I take?

**Ideas** I've considered while reading various discussion:

1. Find a way of disabling the row-wise locks, then compute each new column in a separate query (in parallel). Alternatively, tell postgres that these queries are ok to run in parallel.
2. Compute all columns within a single query, however, split all rows into disjunctive sets. Then, perform these multi-column updated in parallel for individual row groups.
3. Create a new table for each column, compute the metrics in individual queries (saving the results to the new tables). Then, update the final table from the new tables at once.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**: One of the queries is forward-fill of NULL values. Another is basically `(a-b)/c`, however, the more complicated can looks like this (had to rename the tables and columns):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_speak AS (  -- faster than subselect below
    SELECT created
    FROM FTable
    WHERE event = 'speak'
);

WITH FDiff AS (
    SELECT r.id AS id,
        (
            SELECT f.t
            FROM tmp_speak AS f
            WHERE r.created <= f.t
            ORDER by f.t ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ) - r.created as next_speak
    FROM RTable as r
    ORDER BY r.id
)
UPDATE RTable
SET next_speak = FDiff.next_speak
FROM FDiff
WHERE RTable.id = FTable.id
```

Comment: Please post the full update queries, if you are able to do this.

Comment: Once you update a column, the corresponding **row** is locked until that UPDATE is committed. No other transaction will be able to update that row until then (regardless if it wants to update a different column)

Comment: The usual approach to pre-calculating results is to create a query that aggregates the data the way you want and then e.g. create a materialized view from that.

Comment: If all expressions refer to columns from the same row, you could simply create a computed column which will be populated automatically by Postgres

Comment: Also: parallel updates will not reduce the amount of work required. The cost of an update is: fetching a row from disk, and writing it back (twice).

Comment: Thanks for comments. I've provided some query examples.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name regarding the materialized view - how would you accomplish that the columns are computed in parallel? Something like my idea #3, i.e. one view per column?

Comment: Create one query that calculates all expressions at once. That is usually the fastest way to do it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is incredibly slow. Even if I don't update but only select, the parallel version is many times faster (I have hundereds of columns, 64 cores and almost 50x speedup). I'm unable to force postgres to compute in paralllel. The configuration seems fine, though.

Comment: I think the best way to solve your *problem* is to learn SQL before using it. Your query fragment raises several red flags: LIMIT in a scalar subquery, ORDER BY in a subquery, using a CTE or temptable for performance, lack of keyfields. Throwing threads at it is also a sign of procedural thinking. Short answer: updating can be done in about 1/3 of your I/O speed. For 90M (reasonable sized) rows this could be below a minute.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you, you are completely right: my knowledge of sql is very limited. However, my question is rather about running parallel updates than optimizing one of my queries. I understand that by better query I'm able to speed up my code 3x, however, I'd like to speed it approx. number-of-cores times. What are the suggested approaches? Thanks!